# How to Union/Merge three database tables with exact schema but different data while taking care of eloquent relationships?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.7, eloquent-relationship

In my Laravel application, I have three database tables with exact same structure/schema and then there is a 'users' table containing all users.

All three tables have the following structure...

table1

id    user_id    description    updated_at   created_at

1     1             This is nice   xxxxxxxxxx     xxxxxxxxx

2     2             yes right it is   xxxxxxxxxx     xxxxxxxxx

table2

id    user_id    description    updated_at   created_at

1     3             Another text   xxxxxxxxxx     xxxxxxxxx

2     4             And yet more   xxxxxxxxxx     xxxxxxxxx

table3

id    user_id    description    updated_at   created_at

1     5              More nice   xxxxxxxxxx     xxxxxxxxx

2     6             okay done   xxxxxxxxxx     xxxxxxxxx

Now I really want to keep data in these separate tables. However, there is one odd times where I would need to show all these entries from these three tables in a same view, preferably orderedBy created_at field.

I used the following code to union these tables:

```
   $table2 = DB::table('table2');
   $table3 = DB::table('table3');
   $query = DB::table('table1')
        ->union($table1)
        ->union($table3)
        ->get();
```

The problem that arises is that the eloquent relationship doesn't work and this statement in Blade breaks. `{{$comment->user->name}}`.

I just want to be able to union/merge all these three tables and preferably be able to have the relationships or find some other way so that I could get the name of the user who owns a particular entry in the union/merged result. And also have the union/merged result orderedBy created_at column.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Concatenate

*(here's how to do it your way)*

To it in the collections.  Here I'm eager loading user, but you don't have to do that. It will drastically improve performance though.  Note, this is 3 different queries each with a join being executed because of your design choice).

```
$table1 = Table1::with('user')->all();
$table2 = Table2::with('user')->all();
$table3 = Table3::with('user')->all();
$tables = $table1->merge($table2)->merge($table3);
$tables = $tables->sortBy('create_at');
```

### Database and OOP Design

*(here's how you should do it)*

Why do you want them in seperate tables?  It's generally considered by most to bad design to not normalize.  If two objects have the same fields/members, they are the same KIND of object.

If objects have the same fields, they should be the same KIND of object, and you should add a flag for type of that object to get.   So instead of having three tables with

- id
- user_id
- description
- updated_at
- created_at

You'd have one table with the fields:

- id
- user_id
- description
- type
- updated_at
- created_at

Making sure to put an `index` on `type`, so there **is no performance hit** to sticking them all in the same table. Then to get them all  sorted by created_at (note one query, one join):

```
$tables = Table::->orderBy('created_at')->with('user')->get();
```

To get one broken out:

```
$table1 = Table::where('type','=',1)->with('user')->get();
$table2 = Table::where('type','=',2)->with('user')->get();
$table3 = Table::where('type','=',3)->with('user')->get();
```

To get them all, broken out:

```
$tables = Table::->orderBy('created_at')->with('user')->get()->groupBy('type');
```

If one (or more) of the "types" of objects has new fields, then you begin down the road of [inheritance](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships).

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that you want to merge the results of 3 entities: `director`, `teacher`, `student`, all this three entities has the relation `role`:

You could [load the relationships first](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) and then merge the collections using [one](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-merge) of their [many methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections):

```
$directors = Director::with('role')->get();
$teachers = Teacher::with('role')->get();
$students = Student::with('role')->get();

$users = $directors
            ->merge($teachers)
            ->merge($students);
```

Then you could access the relation:

```
dd($users->first()->role->name);
```

#### Observation

Something to keep in mind if you return this values to your view using the `compact` method instead of `with()`:

```
return view('my_view', compact('users'));
```

Then you'll pass an associative array to your view, so in order to access the values in the relationships you'll need to do:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    <h1> {{ $user['role']['name'] }} </h1>
@endforeach
```

Comment: @Kashif was this helpful to you?